# Solidity function generic data type for A[] / B[] parameters

Tags: generics, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

1. I have two structs:
   `Struct A;`
   and
   `Struct B;`
2. I've two arrays:
   `A[] a;` and `B[] b;`
3. And a function: getIndex()

```
//                ^^^*Generic: based on struct type passed*
function getIndex(A/B memory [] arr, string memory _id) internal view returns (uint256){
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen by the `^^^` marks in the function; I need to make function generic for structs A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no such things in Solidity.

In your case you should duplicate your function.

```
    function getIndex(A memory [] arr, string memory _id) internal view returns (uint256){
        // do stuct A specific stuff
        // maybe here a common function call that you want to use in both 
        cases
        return 0;
    }
    
    function getIndex(B memory [] arr, string memory _id) internal view returns (uint256){
        // do stuct A specific stuff
        // maybe here a common function call that you want to use in both 
        cases
        return 0;
    }

   function _commonFunction(xxx) internal {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this increases the contract size(24Kb limit); and I'm totally out of it.